# concatenate the images to single image using opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, concatenation

I am creating a single image from the video. But I read the video and create frames, then after that rotate the frames and crop the frames and these cropped frames are saved.
These cropped frames should be combined to create a single image.
So I have appended them in the vector of Mat and then want to concatenate them horizontally.
Which I did but it doesn't show any image nor the image is saved.

I want to do something similar to python

```
list_images = []
for img in glob.glob(crop_dir + "*.jpg"):
 n = cv2.imread(img,0)
 list_images.append(n)
im_v = np.concatenate(list_images)
cv2.imwrite("finalimg.jpg",im_v)
```

My variable `imglist` is of type
`class std::vector<class cv::Mat,class std::allocator<class cv::Mat> >`

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

string crop_dir = "Task2_Resources/CropImages/";

void delete_dir_content(const fs::path& dir_path) {
    for (auto& path : fs::directory_iterator(dir_path)) {
        fs::remove_all(path);
    }
}

int main() {

    system("CLS");

    if (!fs::is_directory(crop_dir) || !fs::exists(crop_dir)) { // Check if  folder exists
        fs::create_directory(crop_dir); // create  folder
    }
    delete_dir_content(crop_dir);

    VideoCapture vid_capture("Task2_Resources/sample201.avi");

    int count = 0;
    Mat finalimg,mimg;
    vector<cv::Mat> imglist;
    
    Mat image;
    int x = 190, y = 59, h = 1, w = 962;

    if (!vid_capture.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    while (true) {

        Mat frame , rimg;
        vector<Mat> blocks;
        
        
        bool isSuccess = vid_capture.read(frame);
        if (!isSuccess){
            std::cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
            break;
        }

        //imshow("Frames", frame);
        count++;
        float width = frame.cols;
        float height = frame.rows;
        Point2f center = Point2f((width / 2), (height / 2));
        double degree = -0.2;
        double scale = 1.0;
        Mat change = getRotationMatrix2D(center, degree, scale);  // Rotate & scale 
        warpAffine(frame, rimg, change, frame.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        Mat cropped_image = rimg(Range(y,y+h), Range(x, x+w));

        string fname = to_string(count) + ".jpg";
        cv::imwrite(crop_dir + fname, cropped_image);    
        imglist.push_back(cropped_image);



    }
     
    hconcat(imglist,image);
   
   cout << typeid(imglist).name() << endl;
    cv::imwrite("final.jpg", image);
    std::cout << "Total frames created " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio debug console
[image]

Comment: Any error messages? Surely an exception is thrown if you don’t get an output file!

Comment: I don't get any error message nor any exception. I am new to use C++ with openCV and I am using Visual Studio as my IDE. I have attached the screenshot of the Visual Studio Debug Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I could notice is `h = 1` - that makes the height of `cropped_image` to be only 1 pixel.

Since you are not reporting any error message, we can't really tell why it's not working.
I recommend you to use the debugger, and iterate the code step by step (use an IDE for that).

For building a working example, you may follow the stages described next.

---

There is a chance that one of issues is related to `sample201.avi` video file.
For making the answer reproducible, we may use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) CLI for creating synthetic video file:

Please execute the following command from the console (so we have the same input file):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1280x720:duration=3:rate=1 sample.avi
```

The command creates a video file with 3 video frames and resolution 1280x720.
In case you are using Windows, you may need to download FFmpeg (in Linux ffmpeg is usually "built in").

Copy `sample.avi` to `Task2_Resources` folder.

---

Edit your C++ code:
Replace `int x = 190, y = 59, h = 1, w = 962;` with:

```
int x = 190, y = 59, h = 500, w = 962;
```

(Height of `500` pixels is used for example).

Replace `VideoCapture vid_capture("Task2_Resources/sample201.avi");` with `VideoCapture vid_capture("Task2_Resources/sample.avi");`

---

Execute your code.
Make sure 3 JPG images are created in `CropImages` folder.

The output file `final.jpg` is created in the working folder (make sure you have write permissions).

---

Sample output (resized):
[image]

Comment: Got it!!! I realized my mistake about the height of the image. So the required image which i needed would be using `vconcat` instead of `hconcat`. Thank you for the explanation.